# AJAX display .txt info after selecting dropdown option

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need to create a JavaScript file that will pull info from a .txt file according to the selection option. For example, if I select the country "Mexico" then the mexico.txt file should be read and I can then populate the info from that file automatically. How do I go about doing that? Here is my HTML code

```
<div>
    <p>Select a country to see their top 10 most populated cities</p>
    <select>
        <option selected disabled hidden>Select Country</option>
        <option value="USA">Usa</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id = "country"></div>
```

Here is what I have for the JavaScript

```
var countryContainer = document.getElementById("country");

function() {
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'usa.txt');
    ourRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        renderHTML(ourData);
    }
    ourRequest.send();
};
```

The .txt file looks something like this

```
New York            8,143,197
Los Angeles     3,844,829
Chicago         2,842,518
Houston         2,016,582
Philadelphia        1,463,281
Phoenix         1,461,575
San Antonio     1,256,509
San Diego       1,255,540
Dallas          1,213,825
San Jose          912,332
```

Comment: Hi, why not set `value="usa.txt"` same for other options as well ?